# sed is matching passed variable subsets, not exact matches

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I'm partially successfully using sed to replace variables in a text file. I'm stuck on an exception.

A script reads input from a list - say the `$roll_symbol` is `C20`.
sed replaces `C20`, `GC20`, and `KC20` (because `C20` matches part of the string).

I searched the web and tried the variations I found - no success.
I tried these variations without success:

- escape the reserved character $
- escape braces
- escape both
- use double quotes instead of single quotes.

*the best version so far (but only partially):

```
sed -i 's/'${roll_symbol}'/'${roll_symbol}\,${contract_month}'/g'  $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$OUTPUT_FILE;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell sed what characters are legal before the start of your match to limit where it can match. To only match at start-of-word boundaries try `\<`.

```
sed -i "s/\<${roll_symbol}/${roll_symbol},${contract_month}/g"  "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$OUTPUT_FILE";
```